# can't able to access php file from serverside

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mobile, mosync

im newbie to mobile web app development ... now im struggling to connect myphpadmin using mosync sdk...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.2.136:80/ajaxjson/gene.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (output) {
            var i = $.parseJSON(output);
            //  $('#one').append('<p style="font-weight:bold">NEWS LETTER</P>');
            for (var j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
                var title_temp = i[j].Title;
                var title_resized = title_temp.substring(0, 30);
                title_resized = title_resized + "...";

                $('#one').append('<div><p><span style="font-weight:bold" >TITLE</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp: &nbsp; &nbsp;<small><a href=' + i[j].links + '>' + title_resized + '</a></small><br><span style="font-weight:bold" >SOURCE</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :  &nbsp; &nbsp;' + i[j].Source +
                    '<br><span style="font-weight:bold" >CATEGORY</span> &nbsp;: &nbsp; &nbsp;' + i[j].Category + '<hr><p></div>');
                //$('#one').append('<p><div style="background-color:#ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold" >SOURCE</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :  &nbsp; &nbsp;'+i[j].Source+'<p>');
                //$('#one').append('<p><div style="background-color:#ccc" onclick="get"><span style="font-weight:bold" >CATEGORY</span> &nbsp;: &nbsp; &nbsp;'+i[j].Category+'<hr><p></div>');
            }
        },
        erro: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

**Problem:** I put gene.php file in localhost it is working good but if i load the file is server (http://xxxxxx.in/NewsRecord.php) it is not working.I dono how to fix this?help me thanks in advance

Comment: try intelxdk nice one

Comment: It's not a bad idea to just have url: "/ajaxjson/gene.php", as url. That way, when you deploy your script it will be relative to the domain you're working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I tried to access file from another server and It is not possible without the permission and browser wont allow to do that. Then I solved the problem using JSONP in callback.

**Other Server file** : http://xxxxxx.in//NewsRecord.php?callback=?

```
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($output).')';
```

whenever i run this link it print 
**JSONP** data 
({"result":"value"}) like this and i changed dataType to JSONP and its working fine now

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://xxxxxx.in//NewsRecord.php?callback=?",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (output) {
              //working now
                    alert(output.result);

}
});
```